# How does rebase statement work in Bottle SimpleTemplate engine?

Tags: python, template-engine, bottle

I think I don't understand the rebase() function of bottle.
What's the best way to load dynamically a content template into a base template?
The below shown code is not working.

app.py

```
@route("/home")
def home():
    return  template('home.tpl')

@route("/contact")
def contact():
    return  template('contact.tpl')
```

base.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Titel</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
    {{base}}
</body>
</html>
```

home.tpl

```
% rebase('base.tpl')
<b>Hallo World...</b>
```

Comment: "Not working" how?  What is your input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Output over 10.0.2.108:8888/home = % rebase('base.tpl') Hallo World...

Comment: With ''{{!base}}'' it works. The problem was the wrong documentation but now, it is fixed.